# Issue with printing selenium output as the readable text instead of HTML code

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to learn how to web scrape using selenium and have been watching a youtube series by Tech with Tim. I can't get my output of info scraped using selenium to display as text, only HTML code.

I tried this

```
driver.get("https://www.techwithtim.net/")




search = driver.find_element("name","s")
search.send_keys("test")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

try:
    main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "main"))
    )
    articles = main.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "article")
    for article in articles:
        header = article.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "entry-summary")
        print(header.text)
    


finally:
    driver.quit()
```

I was expecting an output with all of the text under the class name entry summary, but instead, i get the error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [70], line 19
     17     articles = main.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "article")
     18     for article in articles:
---> 19         header = article.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "posted-on").text
     20         print(header)
     24 finally:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I understand that the .text has something to do with converting the HTML to text, but I have not been able to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `.find_elements` returns a list of elements not one single element. You need to iterator over the list to get the text of each element.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use `find_element` there, not `find_elements`.
As following:

```py
articles = main.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "article")
for article in articles:
    header = article.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "entry-summary")
    print(header.text)
```